# Unable to resize memory block using realloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I wrote a simple program to implement a dynamic-array based stack. `realloc` has been used to resize the container which I'm using to store the stack elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void stack_push(int **stack, int *stackSize, int element);
int stack_pop(int **stack, int *stackSize);

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int *stack = NULL, stackSize = 0;
    
    do
    {
        printf("\n1. Push\n");
        printf("2. Pop\n");
        printf("Exit (0)\n");
        printf("Enter choice : ");
        scanf("%c", &ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1':
                stack_push(&stack, &stackSize, 1);
                break;
            case '2':
                printf("%d\n", stack_pop(&stack, &stackSize));
                break;
            case '0':
                break;
        }
    } while (ch != '0');

    return 0;
}

void stack_push(int **stack, int *stackSize, int element)
{
    if (!*stack)
    {
        *stack = malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    else
    {
        *stack = realloc(*stack, sizeof(int) * (*stackSize + 1));
    }

    *stack[*stackSize] = element;
    *stackSize += 1;
}

int stack_pop(int **stack, int *stackSize)
{
    if (!*stack)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        *stackSize -= 1;
        int element = *stack[*stackSize];

        if (*stackSize > 0)
        {
            *stack = realloc(*stack, sizeof(int) * (*stackSize));
        }
        else
        {
            free(*stack);
            *stack = NULL;
        }

        return element;
    }
}
```

This program works fine for the first element. But when I try to add subsequent elements, I'm getting a segmentation fault.

I tried debugging my code, and I've found that:

The segmentation fault occurs on the line:

```
*stack[*stackSize] = element;
```

Here's the screenshot showing other details:
[Segmentation Fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqZZT.jpg)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you need to write

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters in the input buffer.

Within the function `stack_push` you have to write:

```
( *stack )[*stackSize] = element;
```

instead of

```
*stack[*stackSize] = element;
```

becuase the subscript operator has a higher precedence then the unary operator `*`.

The same problem exists in the function `stack_pop` where instead of

```
int element = *stack[*stackSize];
```

you have to write:

```
int element = ( *stack )[*stackSize];
```

Also the approach when the function `stack_pop` returns the integer `-1` if the stack is empty

```
int stack_pop(int **stack, int *stackSize)
{
    if (!*stack)
    {
        return -1;
    }
//...
```

is not good. In general `-1` is a valid value that can be stored in the stack.

It would be better to declare the function like:

```
int stack_pop(int **stack, int *stackSize, int *element );
```

That is the function returns `0` if the stack is empty. Otherwise it returns a non-zero value (for example `1`) and sets the variable pointed to by the pointer `element` to the value of an element in the stack.

Alternatively you could add one more function that checks whether the stack is empty. This function should be called before calling the function `stack_pop`.

Also it would be also much better if instead of the separate variables `stack` and `stackSize` you used a structure that contains the corresponding data members as for example:

```
struct Stack
{
    size_t top;
    int *elements;
};
```

And in `main` you could define an object of the structure like:

```
struct Stack stack = { .top = 0, .elements = NULL };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! Could you please suggest some source from where I can learn more about the precedence of declarator operators like *, [ ] etc. I have read about the precedence of arithmetic, logical and relational operators, but this is something new for me.

Comment: @KingoftheSkies You can find a pdf copy of the C Standard Draft in the internet. The subscript operator is a postfix operator. Postfix operators have a higher precedence than unary operators.

Answer (score 6):

It's a precedence issue.  Change:

```
*stack[*stackSize] = element;
```

to:

```
(*stack)[*stackSize] = element;
```

Also change:

```
int element = *stack[*stackSize];
```

to:

```
int element = (*stack)[*stackSize];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood the problem.